# EF 4.1 Nested Complex type to single field

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I could not seem to find an answer to this but what I am trying to do is take a nested complex type and flatten it into the parent table using only the id.

The code is as follows:

```
public class Address
{
    public virtual string Street1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Street2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}
```

The table structure is defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [ClientManagement].[Addresses]
(
    [Id]            INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
    [Street1]       [NVARCHAR](100),
    [Street2]       [NVARCHAR](100),
    [City]          [NVARCHAR](100),
    [ZipCode]       [NVARCHAR](15),
    [RegionId]      [INT]
)
```

Is there any way that I can use EF 4.1 to define this relationship?

Thank you,
Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[ComplexType]
public class Region
{
    [Column("RegionId")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}
```

or this in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Region>().Ignore(r => r.Code);
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Region>().Property(r => r.Id).HasColumnName("RegionId");
```